# HTTP 1.1 corrected_initial_ageに関して

Tags: http

HTTP 1.1の勉強をしています。キャッシュのところでどうしても理解できないところがあります。

corrected_initial_ageが理解できません。

```
  apparent_age = max(0, response_time - date_value);
  corrected_received_age = max(apparent_age, age_value);
  response_delay = response_time - request_time;
  corrected_initial_age = corrected_received_age + response_delay;
```

そもそも、response_delayでresponse_time - request_timeで全体の経過時間を計算しているのに、そこにさらにcorrected_received_ageを加えていますが、なぜでしょうか？

例えば以下の場合：

User <-> Cache A <-> Origin Server

とあった場合、例えばCache Aでのcorrected_initial_ageを求めると
Cache Aでのresponse_timeからCache Aからのrequest_timeの差分を求めた時点で、requestを発行してからresponseを取得するまでの時間が取得できます。
そこに、corrected_received_age、つまりCache Aでのreponse_timeからOrigin Serverがそのresponseを作成した時間をひいたもの、を加えると、余計なことやっているように見えます。

私の理解が間違っているとは思いますが、数式からこのcorected_initial_ageが何を意味しているのかがよく分かりません。

どんなたか分かる方いらっしゃいますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

最初に、Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1    [Request for Comments: 2068]　の　 "13.2.3 Age Calculations"の節から、該当部分を引用します。

> Summary of age calculation algorithm, when a cache receives a
>      response:
>         /*
>          * age_value
>          *      is the value of Age: header received by the cache with
>          *              this response.
>          * date_value
>          *      is the value of the origin server's Date: header
>          * request_time
>          *      is the (local) time when the cache made the request
>          *              that resulted in this cached response
>          * response_time
>          *      is the (local) time when the cache received the
>          *              response
>          * now
>          *      is the current (local) time
>          */
>         apparent_age = max(0, response_time - date_value);
>         corrected_received_age = max(apparent_age, age_value);
>         response_delay = response_time - request_time;
>         corrected_initial_age = corrected_received_age + response_delay;
>         resident_time = now - response_time;
>         current_age   = corrected_initial_age + resident_time;

経過時間に関係するデータとして、サーバの時計で記録した送信時間(date_value)と、経過時間値(age_value)があります。
クライアントの時計とサーバの時計があまりズレていなければ、受信時間(response_time)-送信時間(date_value)で経過時間が求まりますが、時計がずれていると(サーバの時計が進んでいると）受信した後に送信したような矛盾が起きるかもしれません。そうした矛盾を避ける（負の時間ではなく、０にする）ために一つ目の式（下記）が使われます。

```
apparent_age = max(0, response_time - date_value);
```

経過時間値(age_value)は、HTTP/1.1の機能なので、途中にHTTP/1.0のマシンが介在すると不正確なものになります(HTTP/1.0にage_valueの項目はないので、たぶん0になる）そこで、apparent_ageとage_valueのうち良さそうな方を使おうという次式が出てきます。

```
corrected_received_age = max(apparent_age, age_value);
```

複数のマシンで構成されるネットワークシステムでは、すべてのマシンの仕様が合っている、すべてのマシンの時計の同期がとれているというような整った環境が期待できないので、すこしでも"ましな"経過時間を得ようとして（結果として役にたたないかもしれないけど）奮闘しているところが余分にみえるのかもしれません。

Comment: すいません。ちょっとバタバタしていて返事が遅くなりました。ベストなものを選ぶところは何となく理解できるのですが、よく分からないのが、
corrected_initial_age = corrected_received_age + response_delay;
response_delayだけじゃなぜダメなのかがよく分かりません。わざわざcorrected_received_ageを加算している理由はなんでしょうか？

Comment: なんとなく、理解できました。corrected_received_ageはあくまでresponseが作成されてからの経過時間なんですね。メッセージが作成されてから経過した時間(キャッシングされてからの経過時間) + RequestからResponseを受け取るまでの送信経路でかかった時間を割り出しているわけです。そのRequestが発行される大分前にそのデータはキャッシングされている可能性があります。で、わざわざRequestからResponseまでの経過時間を加算しているかというと、送信中に有効期限が切れる可能性があるので、「安全をとって」加算しているわけですね！！いろいろ図に書いてみたら理解できました。